# How to create Grid in sencha touch 2.3.0 populate data from a REST webservice

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I need to display report in Grid / Table in Sencha Touch 2.3.0. Is there any build in function to do so.
The store needs to populate data from a REST webservice call.

Comment: Can anybody share an working example of the same

Answer (score 1):

For loading data you can use [`Ext.data.Store`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store)   configured with REST proxy [`Ext.data.proxy.Rest`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest)

For displaying data from store you can use [`Ext.grid.Grid`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Grid) of [`Ext.dataview.DataView`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.DataView)

Comment: I am still not able to figure out. A sample code or some link will be highly appreciated.

Comment: In my answer you can see four links to documentation where you can also find examples.

Comment: Here you can find detailed exmaple: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/grid_guide

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time with something like this:

(Though I haven't worked with the Grid, I'm quite sure the same principles apply...)

```
Ext.define('App.controller.GridController', {
extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
config: {
    refs: {
        getApiButton: 'button[action=getApiData]'
    },
    control: {
        'getApiButton' : {
            tap : 'onButtonTap'
        }
    }
},

onButtonTap : function(field, value) {

    var that = this;

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : someWebServiceUrl,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function (result, request) {

            var res = Ext.decode(result.responseText);

            if (res.success === true && res.data != false) {

                var recipient = {
                    name:   res.data[0].displayname,
                    picId:  res.data[0].pictureid,
                    gender: res.data[0].gender
                };

                var mod = Ext.define('App.model.GradingPopModel', {
                    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                    config: {
                        fields: [
                            'name',
                            'picId',
                            'gender'
                        ]
                    }
                });

                /* == this is probably where you want to make your changes to apply the model to the grid template
                      the sencha website has this:

                data: {'items': [
                    { 'name': 'Lisa',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-111-1224"  },
                    { 'name': 'Bart',  "email":"bart@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1234" },
                    { 'name': 'Homer', "email":"home@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1244"  },
                    { 'name': 'Marge', "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"  }
                ]}

                */

                var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                    model: mod,
                    storeId:'recipStore'
                });

                store.add(recipient);
                store.setData(recipient);
                store.load();

                var gridView = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#gridViewId')[0];

                gridView.setStore(store);

            }
        },
        failure: function (result, request) {
            console.log('api call was a failure');
        },
        scope: this
    });
}
});
```

Now of course your data won't have "displayname, gender" etc.. but you should get the point.

I also found a working example here (I find it very sad that Sencha allows broken demos on their own website): http://demo.rasc.ch/eds/touch23/grid/grid/index.html